# How get data from entire line in a csv file and print it in txt file using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a hudge csv file with 15 columns and a lot of lines.I use `pandas` to keep only 5 columns in a new csv file.

new csv file.

```
ID, age, number of played game, ratio, Name
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx, 19, 52, 33.0, GhostHotel
```

What i want to do is for each index value extract them from the entire line and print each value in a txt file.

expected task.

`id.txt age.txt number_of_pg.txt ratio.txt Name.txt`

I use the following code but this only print one value in a row.

```
import csv

with open('midvalues.csv') as player:
   csv_reader = csv.reader(player)
   for index, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
      if index == 6:  
         print(row[4])
```

How can i save each value to his specific txt file ?

Comment: I don’t see pandas in your code. You can use slice to print the whole line with `print(row[:])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aligned in the right direction with your code you just need to add some lines to make it work.

```
import csv

id = open(id.txt, 'a')
age = open(age.txt, 'a')
nop = open(number_of_pg.txt, 'a')
ratio = open(ratio.txt, 'a')
name = open(name.txt, 'a')

with open('midvalues.csv') as player:
   csv_reader = csv.reader(player)
   for index, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
      id.write(f"{row[0]}\n")
      age.write(f"{row[1]}\n")
      nop.write(f"{row[2]}\n")
      ratio.write(f"{row[3]}\n")
      name.write(f"{row[4]}\n")
```

This code will print each element of a row separately in different files. you just need to create file empty files before execution of this code.

Comment: Why would you write each row manually? Also, writing the content doesn't necessarily make it a valid CSV (escaping is important)

Comment: I tried to help him in his own approch also the new files he wants are in txt not csv so it will be good to just use \n

Comment: But yes your approch is more optimised.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to save each **column** to a new file, so don't iterate **rows**, and use [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
for col in df:
    df[col].to_csv(f'{col.replace(" ", "_")}.csv',
                   #index=False # uncomment to skip saving the index
                   )
```

Or, for custom names:

```
names = {'ID': 'id',
         'age': 'age',
         'number of played game': 'number_of_pg',
         'ratio': 'ratio',
         'Name': 'Name'}

for col, name in names.items():
    df[col].to_csv(f'{name}.txt')
```

Example output for `Name.txt`:

```
,Name
0,GhostHotel
```